# not a carousel, a list of images

Tags: angular

I'm studing working of carousel. But instead of slides i receive a list of images.
[This example](http://www.angulartypescript.com/angular-2-carousel/)

slide.component.ts

```
    import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

    import {Carousel, Direction} from  './carousel.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'slide',
    template: `
    <div [class.active]="active" class="item text-center">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Slide implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() public index:number;
    @Input() public direction:Direction;

    @HostBinding('class.active')
    @Input() public active:boolean;

    @HostBinding('class.item')
    @HostBinding('class.carousel-item')
    private addClass:boolean = true;

    constructor(private carousel:Carousel) {
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.carousel.addSlide(this);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this.carousel.removeSlide(this);
    }
}
```

carousel.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {Slide} from './slide.component';

export enum Direction {UNKNOWN, NEXT, PREV}

@Component({
    selector: 'carousel',
    template: `
    <div (mouseenter)="pause()" (mouseleave)="play()" class="carousel slide">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators" [hidden]="slides.length <= 1">
         <li *ngFor="let slidez of slides" [class.active]="slidez.active === true" (click)="select(slidez)"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
                  <a class="left carousel-control" (click)="prev()" [hidden]="!slides.length">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" (click)="next()" [hidden]="!slides.length">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                 </a>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Carousel implements OnDestroy {
    @Input() public noWrap:boolean;
    @Input() public noPause:boolean;
    @Input() public noTransition:boolean;

    @Input() public get interval():number {
        return this._interval;
    }

    public set interval(value:number) {
        this._interval = value;
        this.restartTimer();
    }

    private slides:Array<Slide> = [];
    private currentInterval:any;
    private isPlaying:boolean;
    private destroyed:boolean = false;
    private currentSlide:Slide;
    private _interval:number;

    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroyed = true;
    }

    public select(nextSlide:Slide, direction:Direction = Direction.UNKNOWN) {
        let nextIndex = nextSlide.index;
        if (direction === Direction.UNKNOWN) {
            direction = nextIndex > this.getCurrentIndex() ? Direction.NEXT : Direction.PREV;
        }

        // Prevent this user-triggered transition from occurring if there is already one in progress
        if (nextSlide && nextSlide !== this.currentSlide) {
            this.goNext(nextSlide, direction);
        }
    }

    private goNext(slide:Slide, direction:Direction) {
        if (this.destroyed) {
            return;
        }

        slide.direction = direction;
        slide.active = true;

        if (this.currentSlide) {
            this.currentSlide.direction = direction;
            this.currentSlide.active = false;
        }

        this.currentSlide = slide;

        // every time you change slides, reset the timer
        this.restartTimer();
    }

    private getSlideByIndex(index:number) {
        let len = this.slides.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            if (this.slides[i].index === index) {
                return this.slides[i];
            }
        }
    }

    private getCurrentIndex() {
        return !this.currentSlide ? 0 : this.currentSlide.index;
    }

    private next() {
        let newIndex = (this.getCurrentIndex() + 1) % this.slides.length;

        if (newIndex === 0 && this.noWrap) {
            this.pause();
            return;
        }

        return this.select(this.getSlideByIndex(newIndex), Direction.NEXT);
    }

    private prev() {
        let newIndex = this.getCurrentIndex() - 1 < 0 ? this.slides.length - 1 : this.getCurrentIndex() - 1;

        if (this.noWrap && newIndex === this.slides.length - 1) {
            this.pause();
            return;
        }

        return this.select(this.getSlideByIndex(newIndex), Direction.PREV);
    }

    private restartTimer() {
        this.resetTimer();
        let interval = +this.interval;
        if (!isNaN(interval) && interval > 0) {
            this.currentInterval = setInterval(() => {
                let nInterval = +this.interval;
                if (this.isPlaying && !isNaN(this.interval) && nInterval > 0 && this.slides.length) {
                    this.next();
                } else {
                    this.pause();
                }
            }, interval);
        }
    }

    private resetTimer() {
        if (this.currentInterval) {
            clearInterval(this.currentInterval);
            this.currentInterval = null;
        }
    }

    public play() {
        if (!this.isPlaying) {
            this.isPlaying = true;
            this.restartTimer();
        }
    }

    public pause() {
        if (!this.noPause) {
            this.isPlaying = false;
            this.resetTimer();
        }
    }

    public addSlide(slide:Slide) {
        slide.index = this.slides.length;
        this.slides.push(slide);
        if (this.slides.length === 1 || slide.active) {
            this.select(this.slides[this.slides.length - 1]);
            if (this.slides.length === 1) {
                this.play();
            }
        } else {
            slide.active = false;
        }
    }

    public removeSlide(slide:Slide) {
        this.slides.splice(slide.index, 1);

        if (this.slides.length === 0) {
            this.currentSlide = null;
            return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
            this.slides[i].index = i;
        }
    }
}
```

and the code of using

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Slide} from './slide.component';
import {Carousel} from './carousel.component';


/*Angular 2 Carousel - Gallery*/
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:`
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <carousel [interval]="NextPhotoInterval" [noWrap]="noLoopSlides">
                          <slide *ngFor=" let slidez of slides; let i=index"
                                 [active]="slidez.active">
                            <img [src]="slidez.image" style="margin:auto;">

                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                              <h3 style="background-color: transparent;color: white;">Slide {{i + 1}}</h3>
                              <p  style="background-color: transparent;color: white;">{{slidez.text}}</p>
                            </div>
                          </slide>
                        </carousel>
                      </div>

                    </div>

             `,
})
export class Angular2Carousel  {
    //The time to show the next photo
    private NextPhotoInterval:number = 5000;
    //Looping or not
    private noLoopSlides:boolean = true;
    //Photos
    private slides:Array<any> = [];

    constructor() {
            this.addNewSlide();
    }

    private addNewSlide() {
         this.slides.push(
            {image:'http://www.angulartypescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/car1.jpg',text:'BMW_1'},
            {image:'http://www.angulartypescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/car2.jpg',text:'BMW_2'},
            {image:'http://www.angulartypescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/car3.jpg',text:'BMW_3'},
            {image:'http://www.angulartypescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/car4.jpg',text:'BMW_4'},
            {image:'http://www.angulartypescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/car5.jpg',text:'BMW_5'},
            {image:'http://www.angulartypescript.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/car6.jpg',text:'BMW_6'}
        );
    }

    private removeLastSlide() {
        this.slides.pop();
    }
}
```

Can you please explain this result. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Zsx.jpg)

Comment: You’re obviously missing required CSS declarations.

Comment: There was no any css file in example

Comment: That tutorial even says *“Include bootstrap before we start”*

Comment: Sorry!
<link href=”https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/x.x.x/css/bootstrap.min.css” rel=”stylesheet”> Where i should write this?

Comment: i add it to index.html file, but there is no any changes

Comment: Thank you very much!!! i should write this two string <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng2-bootstrap/x.x.x/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> into html file